# A few Haskell errors I can't seem to figure out

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to make a Tetris game using haskell for class.

Right now i'm trying to implement printing out just a board from a given input.

I ran into some erros. I'm basing my code of off an example my prof gave that is somewhat similar.

The errors

```
assign3.hs:20:5: error:
The type signature for ‘leftToRight’ lacks an accompanying binding
|
20 |     leftToRight :: Int -> Board -> String -> [Char]    |     
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My code

```
module Main where
import Text.Printf (printf)
import Test.HUnit
import Data.Set (empty,member,delete,insert,Set)
main = do
     input <- getContents
     putStr $ show $ readFrom input

class Disp a where
     disp :: a -> String
data Square = Empty deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
instance Disp Square where
     disp Empty = " "
type BoardCell = (Square,Int)
type Board = [BoardCell]
data Game = Game Board Int
instance Show Game where
     show(Game board width)=
         printBoard width board $ lefToRight width board
leftToRight :: Int -> Board -> String -> String
lefToRight width [] = ""
lefToRight width board = (lefToRight width $ drop width board) ++ ("|" ++ formatRow $ take width board ++ "|\n")
rowBreak :: a -> String
rowBreak row =
     foldr (\x -> \y -> "-" ++ y) "+\n" row
formatRow :: Board -> String
formatRow row =
     foldr (\x -> \y -> "" ++ row1 x ++ y) "" row
row1 :: BoardCell -> String
row1 (square,int) = disp square
printBoard :: Int -> Board -> String -> String
printBoard width [] string = string ++ rowBreak(replicate width 0)
printBoard width [(_,_)] string = printBoard width [] string
printBoard width (_:rest) string = printBoard width rest string

emptyBoard = Game [] 1
readFrom = foldr doLine emptyBoard . lines
doLine game = doCommand game . words

doCommand :: Game -> [String] -> Game
doCommand (Game _ width) ["board",cols,rows] =
             Game (take (int rows*width) $ zip (cycle [Empty]) (iterate succ 1))
                 width
                     where width = int cols

int :: String -> Int
int = read
```

What i'm trying to do is take input like "board 7 4" and get an output like this

```
          |       |
          |       |
          |       |
          |       |
          +-------+
```

Comment: You should give type signatures to everything.  `printBoard`, `readrom`, `doLine`, `rowBreak`.  I think it will help you find the errors.

Comment: Without proper signatures, GHC can not know what you actually intend to do, and will assign the inferred types to your functions, possibly getting them wrong, and causing type errors to show up elsewhere, in the middle of perfectly fine code. I'd also recommend to turn on warnings.

Comment: Updated the code and added type signatures. Solved all the error issues I was getting. Now getting this one i'm not sure about

Comment: Your signature is for `leftToRight`, but your implementation is for `lefToRight`.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Wagner pointed out in the question comments, you have a misspelling. `leftToRight` is used in the type signature, which is spelled correctly. `lefToRight` is used for the function definition, but that's misspelled.

So, the type signature doesn't have a function definition of the exact same name, which gives the error you got.